# How to lock elements to the right of the screen on Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview

As the title says, im making a custom list view and I cant seem to lock the 2 buttons to the right of each item

Here´s my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/registro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        >
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/config"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tought that just by adding the " android:marginEnd = "0dp" " it would be enough, but that doesnt seem to do it. I also tried changing the gravity and it also didnt work

[image: Here is how it looks when running]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the "value" TextView

Comment: I think that worked, but it stretched my buttons, is there a way to keep the size but do the same thing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put in LinearLayout and than apply layout_weight to each layout instead of applying weight to individual view. Like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Camara #2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Camera 2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cant"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
  
  android:gravity="end" ##remove this if you want buttons should adjust/move 
   with text, otherwise if you to fix them at last dont remove
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageButton
    android:id = "@+id/registro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/config"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

</ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```